# How to Efficiently Perform Multiplication within MultiIndex Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am trying to use two of my second level indices to calculate a third index. However, I can't find an idiomatic way to do this.

How can I calculate one second level index from two other second level indices? Each group has the same second level indices.

### My Code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create index
tickers = ['A', 'B', 'C']
line_items = ['sales', 'ebitda_margin', 'ebitda', 'other_field']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([tickers, line_items], names=['ticker', 'line_item'])

df = pd.DataFrame([100, 0.3, np.nan, 7, 200, 0.2, np.nan, 8, 300, 0.1, np.nan, 9], 
                  index=index, 
                  columns=[0])

# Let's assume 10% sales growth for all companies
# This is included to show that I am doing this calculation for multiple years (columns)
df[1] = df[0]
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'sales'], 1] *= 1.1
```

This produces the following data frame:

```
                          0      1
ticker line_item                  
A      sales          100.0  110.0
       ebitda_margin    0.3    0.3
       ebitda           NaN    NaN
       other_field      7.0    7.0
B      sales          200.0  220.0
       ebitda_margin    0.2    0.2
       ebitda           NaN    NaN
       other_field      8.0    8.0
C      sales          300.0  330.0
       ebitda_margin    0.1    0.1
       ebitda           NaN    NaN
       other_field      9.0    9.0
```

### What I Have

*Note that I know that I will need to do some work with indexes to get the below to work, but would rather find a better way if one exists rather than using this code.*

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'sales']] * x.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'ebitda_margin']])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `df.stack().unstack('line_item').eval('ebitda = ebitda_margin * sales').stack().unstack(1)`?

Comment: This works well @piRSquared. Is there any way to make it into multiple lines and replace the eval statement with something else? EDIT: I found a way to do this in a few lines. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Yes! I think.  Please post what you want your final dataframe to look like.  Also, don't be scared of `pd.DataFrame.eval`  It isn't your normal Python `eval`.

Comment: I posted an answer referencing your comment. Thank you again, @piRSquared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xs` as an alternative to `pd.IndexSlice` where you get to remove one level, then `mul` which allows level alignment when multiply:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'sales'],:] = (df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'sales'],:]
                                         .mul(df.xs('ebitda_margin', level='line_item'), level=0)
                                      )
```

Output:

```
                         0
ticker line_item          
A      sales          30.0
       ebitda_margin   0.3
       ebitda          NaN
       other_field     7.0
B      sales          40.0
       ebitda_margin   0.2
       ebitda          NaN
       other_field     8.0
C      sales          30.0
       ebitda_margin   0.1
       ebitda          NaN
       other_field     9.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to set ebitda to sales * ebitda_margin. I think this is messing up indices, which causes it to not be set correctly.

Comment: Nevermind, if I just grab the values and set using index slice this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == "sales"] = (
    df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == "sales"].values
    * df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == "ebitda_margin"].values
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         0     1
ticker line_item                
A      sales          30.0  33.0
       ebitda_margin   0.3   0.3
       ebitda          NaN   NaN
       other_field     7.0   7.0
B      sales          40.0  44.0
       ebitda_margin   0.2   0.2
       ebitda          NaN   NaN
       other_field     8.0   8.0
C      sales          30.0  33.0
       ebitda_margin   0.1   0.1
       ebitda          NaN   NaN
       other_field     9.0   9.0
```

Comment: is there a way for me to set the ebitda indices to sales * ebitda_margin?

Comment: @JackMoody Just change "sales" to "ebidta". Try `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == "ebitda"] = ...the same...`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @piRSquared for helping me out with this. The following did it for me:

---

piR comments:
The point is to get the line items into columns to make the math easier.  If the dataframe is oriented for presentation and is small, it's quick enough to `stack`/`unstack`/`pivot` to do your calculations more conveniently, then `stack`/`unstack`/`pivot` back.

---

```py
df_restack = df.stack().unstack('line_item')
df_restack['ebitda'] = df_restack['sales'] * df_restack['ebitda_margin']
df = df_restack.stack().unstack(1)
```

This produces the following data frame:

```
                          0      1
ticker line_item                  
A      ebitda          30.0   33.0
       ebitda_margin    0.3    0.3
       other_field      7.0    7.0
       sales          100.0  110.0
B      ebitda          40.0   44.0
       ebitda_margin    0.2    0.2
       other_field      8.0    8.0
       sales          200.0  220.0
C      ebitda          30.0   33.0
       ebitda_margin    0.1    0.1
       other_field      9.0    9.0
       sales          300.0  330.0
```

I will note that the answers by Quang and Andrej are much faster when the data frame is larger, so I have selected Quang's answer, as he answered first.